# How to map an integer array in JPA

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring jpa with hibernate and postgres

In an entity, I tried to use a List and integer[]

In the database, I have a column of type:

```
integer[]
```

is there any jpa way to use it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JPA is not able to persist arrays to a separate table or database array (e.g. ones mapped to `java.sql.Array`) out of the box. So you have two ways:

1) Use `@Lob` to save this column as BLOB or CLOB

```
@Lob
private Integer[] values;
```

2) Use `List<Integer>` instead of an array

```
@ElementCollection
public List<Integer> values;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just doing this worked fine for me:

```
@Column(name="column_name")
private Integer[] columnName;
```

I didn't need `@Lob` like Mykola Yashchenko suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your custom generic array converter to resolve this issue.

Comment: Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.